# ConEmu - Open Explorer with current directory

Tags: console, explorer, conemu

I use PowerShell with [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/). Is it possible to open the Windows Explorer from ConEmu with its current directory?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just run from your PowerShell prompt

```
start .
```

Comment: No way, it is really that easy. Thanks!